# Ajax codes not work on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, mobile

this code works perfectly on the desktop browser , and works also on the mobile application

```
function submitSN()
{
    var data = [];

    var eles1 = document.getElementsByClassName('chip');

    for (var i = 0 ; i < eles1.length ; i++)
    {
        data.push(eles1[i].innerText.substring(0,eles1[i].innerText.length-5));
    }

    profile.skills = data;
    profile.uid = uid;

        $.ajax({
        url: '/postprof',
        type:'POST',
        data: profile,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })});
        $("body").html("<h1 style='text-align:center;padding:4%;'>Done, Return to your messenger now!</h1>");
}
```

but it does not send the Ajax calls on the mobile browsers , I means this code exactly

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/postprof',
    type:'POST',
    data: profile,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })});
```

this code works on the normal desktop browser , but not work on my mobile browser , how to fix this issue ??

Comment: Do you have the url?

Comment: Take a look at this site, maybe it will help you with your problem https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_browser_support.htm

Comment: Phone Gap? You need to have COORS Access on your Server Page, because that App is not on your Domain.

Comment: @PHPglue , not this problem , because it works on the desktop browsers normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need define any headers, the default settings for jQuery ajax is handling json anyway.

here is a very basic `POST` request with jQuery ajax that send a simple object, you don't need to define `headers`, `dataType` or `contentType`.

```
let custom_object = {
    name: 'Ahmed',
    age: 22
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'YOUR_URL',
    data: custom_object,
    success: function(){
        cosnole.log('Done: ', e)
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log('ERROR! ', e);
    }
});
```

There default values is:

- `headers`: `{}`
- `dataType`: `Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)`
- `contentType`: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The line that fails is probably this:

```
headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })});
```

You're probably testing on an iPhone/iOS/Webkit which doesn't have a `Headers` constructor.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers)

Answer (score 0):

The Headers API is only available in certain browsers.

Take a look at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Headers#Browser_compatibility) table

Try this instead : 
`contentType: "application/json",`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/postprof',
    type:'POST',
    data: profile,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
 });
```

Comment: Did you try on BrowserStack or the iPhone debugger?

Comment: I test on the normal Safari Browser , here's the URL to check it
http://urlgone.com/3bad68/

Comment: skip the ad ,sorry :D

Comment: When submitting the form I received a 404 (http://lancerbot.herokuapp.com/postprof). The problem on the server not the client. I'm maybe wrong.

Comment: I think apple protect their users from any HTTP requests , then no XMLHttpRequest object can be created and then noway to achieve that on safari -- reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_browser_support.htm

Comment: did you test that on the browser ??

Comment: the free server on heroku sometimes sleep , it's another issue -- I need to solve the ajax support on mobile issue ..

Comment: Both mobile and desktop version doesn't work. There is something with your express app.

Comment: Yes , there's some errors here : http://i.imgur.com/z3MTnyD.png

-- but it normally not makes these errors , did you provide a correct info from the form on the page , and did not change the url .. etc